# Unable to install YAML for Python2.7 on my mac

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to install YAML module (PyYAML3.10) for Python 2.7 on my mac. I get the foll error message:

```
$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running install_lib
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/yaml
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/yaml': Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of permissions... Try with: `sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: Thanks everyone. It was a matter of permissions i used sudo and i am able to install. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear:

```
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/yaml': Permission denied
```

You don't have permission to write to this directory.  If you run `setup.py` using `sudo`, you'll run it with root privileges, which will let you install it:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

You may want to look into something like [macports](http://www.macports.org), which gives you a convenient way of installing (and uninstalling, ugrading, etc) a variety of open source software.  It includes packaged versions of the YAML module.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use [pip](http://pip-installer.org/) to install the package and [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to make pip install packages as your user. This way you won't get anymore `Permission denied` messages. See [this guide](http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/) for learning more about virtualenv. It might seem a bit hard to grip at first but I promise you that the effort is well worth it.